# Phing SSH connection to Amazon EC2 fails to authenticate

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to connect to Amazon EC2 with phing. This is my script.

```
    <ssh username="ec2-user"
         pubkeyfile="C:\Users\asd\Downloads\aws-nr1.public"
         privkeyfile="C:\Users\asd\Downloads\aws-nr1.pem"
         host="some.domain.com"
         command="ls -l" />
```

I've got the PEM key file directly from Amazon, and I generated PUBLIC key file by puttygen. Result:

```
[PHP Error] ssh2_auth_pubkey_file(): Authentication failed for ec2-user using public key
```

I've no idea what I'm doing with the key files, but I want it to connect and run `ls -l`. Anybody had it working?

Comment: The actual PHP command is this: `$could_auth = ssh2_auth_pubkey_file($this->connection, $this->username, $this->pubkeyfile, $this->privkeyfile, $this->privkeyfilepassphrase);`. What is privkeyfilepassphrase? And why does it need both public and private key files? I think private is enough. That's how ssh/putty is working for me with just private file.

Comment: I assume you are running Amazon Linux and not Ubuntu?